# Check the accuracy of vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I learning AI with Python and have this situation: I created a deep learning model that has 10 neurons in his Input layer. On the output layer I have 3 neurons. I split up my data to 80% for learning and 20% for testing.

The trained model is ready for testing.

Until now, I always got situation that I have only one neuron in the output layer. So, I tested the accuracy in that way:

```
classifier = Sequential()
# ...
classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
# ...
y_pred = classifier.predict(np.array(X_test))
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

which working great when the output layer has only ONE value on each prediction.

In my case, I have 3 values in each prediction.

```
y_pred = array ([[3.142904686503911194e-11, 1.000000000000000000e+00, 1.729809626091548085e-16],
[7.398544450698540942e-12, 1.000000000000000000e+00, 1.776427415878292515e-22],
[4.224535246066807304e-07, 1.000000000000000000e+00 7.929732391553923065e-12]])
```

And I want to compare it to my expected values, which:

```
y_test = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

So, I have the option to make this work manually:

1. Put 1 in the highest value in the prediction value. Other values are getting 0.
2. Compare the two vectors row by row.

It looks like must have a better way to do it?

Comment: take a look at `numpy.allclose(array1, array2)`. It compares two arrays element-wise and returns True if each pair of elements is equal within a certain tolerance

Answer (score 1):

You want to measure how "close" the prediction vector is to the expected vector. A good formula that describes the "amount of difference" between two vectors is to check the magnitude (or square magnitude) of the delta vector (prediction - expected).

In this case, you can do something like this:

```
def square_magnitude(vector):
    return sum(x*x for x in vector)

def inaccuracy(pred, test):  #should only get equal-length items
    return square_magnitude([pred[i] - test[i] for i in range(len(pred))]) / len(pred)
```

Since you have three samples:

```
total_inaccuracy = sum(inaccuracy(y_pred[i], y_test[i]) for i in range(len(y_pred))) / len(y_pred)
```

This should be 0 when it's perfectly accurate and higher (positive) when it's less accurate.

Comment: Thanks for advice. You missing "()" on your `sum` method. I just run your code and got the output `array([16.34357647,  4.65592751, 16.07208552])`. How to get the accuracy in term of percents?

Comment: Thanks - fixed. I also failed to notice that you have three vectors (updated and expanded answer to account).

Comment: You can't get the accuracy in percentage because it can be infinitely wrong (e.g. if the prediction is -999 and the expectation is 1...). However, since it seems like you always expect either 0 or 1, perhaps you could say that the maximum inaccuracy is a delta of 1 in each: this would result in a value of `1` since we divide by the amount of tests.

Comment: As you said, I always expect to get binary value. So, the only 3 values are `[1, 0, 0]`, `[0, 1, 0]` and `[0, 0, 1]`. I think that I need to add another step that convert the prediction to those values. For example, the vector `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` change to `[0, 0, 1]` (since the element in index 2 has the highest probability). I'm wrong?

Comment: After running your code, I got the value `0.0902`. Does it mean that it 91% accurate?

Comment: There are two kinds of accuracy - if you want to check how accurate your final prediction is, then you should indeed add that step you described. If you want to check how "certain" your prediction is then you shouldn't do that - for example, there's a difference between getting [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] and getting [0.0001, 0.0001, 0.9998] even though the final prediction would be the same for both.

Comment: The value `91% = 1-0.902` is the second accuracy I described.

If you add your step of rounding to 0 and 1, then your accuracy in this case would become a perfect `1.0` if I read your data right. This is good, it's just less useful if you want to make small changes to your neural network and see how it reacts.